# exit out of all SSH connections in one command and close PuTTY

Tags: linux, ssh, windows, putty, exit

Is there a way to back out of all SSH connections and close [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) in "one shot"?  I work in Windows 7 and use PuTTY to SSH to various Linux hosts.

An example of the way I find myself working:

```
SSH to host1 with PuTTY...
banjer@host1:~> #...doin some work...ooh! need to go check something on host8...
banjer@host1:~> ssh host8
banjer@host8:~> #...doin some work...OK time for lunch. lets close putty...
banjer@host8:~> exit
banjer@host1:~> exit
Putty closes.
```

Per above, any way to get from host8 to closing PuTTY in one shot?  Sometimes I find myself up to 5 or 10 hosts deep.  I realize I can click the X to close the PuTTY window, but I like to make sure my SSH connections get closed properly by using the exit command.  I also realize I'm asking for tips on how to increase laziness.  I'll just write it off as "how can I be more efficient".

Comment: Not directly what you are asking but how about just pressing `ctrl+d` multiple times?

Comment: @UlrichDangel I have never used that before, but also a quick way to back out of connections quickly.

Comment: Are you really nesting ssh sessions 5 to 10 levels deep?  Do you realize that's creating a convoluted tunnel that bounces all packets in your ssh session through all of those hosts?  Could you make the problem go away by simply not nesting ssh sessions?

Comment: @jw013 No, I did not realize that, but makes sense.  Honestly, 5-10 levels was an exaggeration, but I was trying to illustrate my question of "how to cleanly exit out of Putty in one fell swoop."

Comment: Sometimes the nested sessions can be for different users (e.g. root, nginx, user, ...) on the same host.  Just one host to host tunnel, but multiple shells on the remote host.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try using the `ssh` connection termination escape sequence.

In the `ssh` session, enter `~.` (tilde dot). You won't see the characters when you type them, but the session will terminate immediately.

```
$ ~.
$ Connection to me.myhost.com closed.
```

From `man 1 ssh`

```
The supported escapes (assuming the default ‘~’) are:
 ~.      Disconnect.
 ~^Z     Background ssh.
 ~#      List forwarded connections.
 ~&      Background ssh at logout when waiting for forwarded 
         connection / X11 sessions to terminate.
 ~?      Display a list of escape characters.
 ~B      Send a BREAK to the remote system (only useful for SSH protocol
         version 2 and if the peer supports it).
 ~C      Open command line.  Currently this allows the addition of port 
         forwardings using the -L, -R and -D options (see above). It also
         allows the cancellation of existing remote port-forwardings using 
         -KR[bind_address:]port.  !command allows the user to execute a 
         local command if the PermitLocalCommand option is enabled in
         ssh_config(5).  Basic help is available, using the -h option.
 ~R      Request rekeying of the connection (only useful for SSH protocol 
         version 2 and if the peer supports it).
```

Comment: Pretty cool!  Any way to put `~.` into an alias or function?  Just to give it an easy to remember name like `exitall`.  Now I'm asking for way too much :).  I tried a few things in `~/.bashrc` but get `-bash: ~.: command not found`.  I suppose bash sees it as a string and not an escape sequence coming directly from the keyboard.

Comment: I like the `ctrl+d` solution as well, but this answers my question more directly.  Thanks all.

Comment: @Banjer bash never sees `~.`, it's handled by `ssh` itself.

Comment: @Gilles gotcha, makes sense.

Comment: And there's no guarantee that PuTTY also does this. The CLI `ssh` client needs this technique because it's CLI. PuTTY is a GUI application and there are far more user-friendly ways to do this stuff on a GUI.

Comment: Interesting.  I've never heard of these `ssh` features until today.  PuTTY doesn't seem to have them though.

Answer (score 18):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to exit and it will log you out. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>D</kbd> repeatedly to log you out of multiple windows, tabs, or levels until the window disappears.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work universally. Any session running an editor or other full screen tool is likely to ignore `EOT`. And even `bash` will ignore it in the middle of a command line. Try it out yourself: type a single letter and try `Ctrl-D`.

Comment: What does Ctrl + D does, i mean is it safely exists or just kills the process ?

Comment: It safely exits. It is a shell shortcut that is the same as typing 'exit' and pressing enter.

Comment: Actually mine (windows git bash & ubuntu bash) issue a `logout`.

Comment: yes, I believe exit also calls logout as ssh connections tend not to be login sessions.

Answer (score 9):

Simply close PuTTY. (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> by default IIRC.)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind doing a little scripting you can do this.

Script: myssh.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh $1
if [ $? -eq 5 ]; then
 exit 5
fi
```

Call via the dot command:

```
$ . myssh user@server.com
```

If you want to exit one level:

```
$ exit
```

If you want to exit all:

```
$ exit 5
```

Comment: Of course, you would have copy it to every computer that you may ever ssh from. Also, wouldn't it be easier to just define a shell function called ssh? That would avoid the preceeding period, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to make `function` for `ssh`:

```
   function ssh(){ /usr/bin/ssh $@ ; exit ; }
```

Unfortunately it also will always close the connection and logout from console after you'll finish work on the remote system.

Note, that you need make such function at all your servers, otherwise this hack won't work. Btw you can always put function into ~/.bashrc or ~/.whatever_shell_you_use_rc .

It looks a little bit dirty hack comparing to uther's way.

Comment: `function` is not POSIX -- just remove the keyword, and you need to quote `$@` properly, or your arguments will be passed after word splitting (bad).

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use `exec` to replace your shell process with `ssh` when jumping to another host:

```
SSH to host1 with PuTTY...
banjer@host1:~> #...doin some work...ooh! need to go check something on host8...
banjer@host1:~> exec ssh host8
banjer@host8:~> #...doin some work...OK time for lunch. lets close putty...
banjer@host8:~> exit
Putty closes.
```

5 levels deep is not pretty, since the traffic will pass through all the other servers. Because of that I don't recommend just killing PuTTY or ssh (~.), since (depending on what you do) this could result in orphaned processes on the servers.

Better to try and be less "lazy". Right-click on puttys title bar makes opening a new session quick. If you have a "default" server and accept 1 jump from that, the "Duplicate Session" feature is very useful. Especially when using pubkey authentication.

Answer (score -1):

Typing logout in the putty terminal window does it for me:

```
richard@forevermore:~ > logout
```

Closes the ssh connection and quits the Putty Application.

Comment: I believe that you didn't read the question correctly. OP does ``ssh host1``, and then, from `host1`, does ``ssh host8``. At that point a `logout` would do the same thing as the `exit` command they already know — exit out of `host8` and put them back into `host1`.

Comment: Ok, I see, my bad.